# Wordpress: Change color palette on reload

Tags: wordpress, colors, wordpress-theming, themes, color-palette

There is a pre-made color palette in WordPress that are applied to the website elements. I want on a website that on each reload the color palette changes. I would predefine circa 5 color palettes, and it will always select a random one each time the page is reloaded.

Is this possible with CSS, Javascript or some kind of a plugin?

I have already searched the internet for a solution, but have not found anything suitable.

Answer (score 0):

IF you creating entire stylesheet, yu can have

```
:root {
    --accent-one: #F7586B;
    --accent-two: #F79D71;
}
```

colors set and use them in styles as

```
color: var(--accent-one);
background-color: var(--accent-two);
```

when you want to change it on every page reload just dump inline styling settting and new colours.